# How to return data from $.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function that loads game map from json file.

```
function newTileMapFromJSON(src) {
    var mymap;
    $.getJSON(src, function(data) {

        [...]

        var finalData = {
            map: tMap,
            tiles: blocks,
            name: MapName
        };

        return finalData;
    });
}
```

But it won't work. There is "return" but in function inside "getJSON". I've no idea how to get "finalData" and return it.

```
function newTileMapFromJSON(src) {
    var mymap;
    var finalData;
    $.getJSON(src, function(data) {

        [...]

        var finalData = {
            map: tMap,
            tiles: blocks,
            name: MapName
        };

    });
    return finalData;
}
```

This code doesn't work, returned finalData is undefined. Maybe getJSON works in another thread? I don't know.

How would you do that, if you were me?

Comment: `$.getJSON` is an async call, so you'll need to use callback functions to get the data out.

Comment: You can't. don't try to get around it. Ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: the "deferred" object in the linked question would be appropriate here, because you can use `.then` to pre-process the received data before passing it back to the intended receipient.

Comment: @Alnitak is right. You should just return `getJSON().promise()`

Comment: @Andbdrew You don't need to use `.promise()` on `.getJSON()`, but it won't hurt anything either.

Comment: @Andbdrew there's no need for `.promise()` - the `getJSON()` result is already a promise object.  I would use `return getJSON(...).then(function(data) { ... ; return finalData } })`.

Comment: @KevinB it can hurt - it strips the non-promise properties from the `jqXHR` object.

Comment: I wish I hadn't close-voted this now - sometimes it helps to give specific advice, even though the question is almost exactly the same as other questions.

Comment: @Alnitak when I'm returning a promise, I want to remove the non-promise properties of the jqXHR object.

Comment: @Andbdrew why?  They can contain useful AJAX related information.  They _don't_ include the properties that allow you to change the promise's state.

Comment: @Alnitak I don't want consumers of my promises to be able to manipulate the state of the promise.

Comment: @Andbdrew that's what I just said.  You _can't_ manipulate the state of the promise with the `jqXHR` - the other "deferred" methods don't exist on it.